# delete-selection-mode and $

Tags: auctex, delete-selection-mode

Using Aquamacs 3.2 on Mac OSX Yosemite. I run with `delete-selection-mode` set, and it mostly works as advertised. However, if I'm in TeX mode (AucTeX), make a selection, and then type `$`, the selection is cleared and the `$` appended. So for example if I select `foobar` in `xyzfoobarxyz` and type `$`, I get `xyzfoobar$xyz` instead of the desired `xyz$xyz`. Is this known/documented behavior, or a bug? If it's a bug, is it an AucTeX or an Aquamacs issue (or an Emacs issue)?

Edit: In response to Tobias' comment below, `C-h k $` returns

> $ runs the command TeX-insert-dollar, which is an interactive compiled
>   Lisp function in `tex.el'.
>
> It is bound to $.
>
> (TeX-insert-dollar &optional ARG)
>
> Insert dollar sign.
>
> If current math mode was not entered with a dollar, refuse to insert
>   one.  Show matching dollar sign if this dollar sign ends the TeX math
>   mode and 'blink-matching-paren' is non-nil. When outside math mode,
>   the behavior is controlled by the variable 'TeX-electric-math'.
>
> With raw ^U prefix, insert exactly one dollar sign.  With optional
>   ARG, insert that many dollar signs.

And, the function `delete-selection-mode` is defined in `delsel.el`.

I'm far from LISP-literate. Perhaps the `TeX-insert-dollar` function does not take the delete selection mode into account (either by design or by omission)?

Comment: Probably `$` runs some special command in AucTeX, and that command isn't marked to as an insertion command, see [delsel.el commentary](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/delsel.el?id=emacs-24.5#n34)

Comment: According to @npostavs's comment, try this `(put 'TeX-insert-dollar 'delete-selection t)`

Comment: @xuchunyang That did not work; it seeming had no effect. I tried both `TeX-insert...` and `LaTeX-insert...`.

Comment: You should give some more info. What does `C-h k $` deliver? When you input `C-h f delete-selection-mode RET` what file is this function defined in? (As I understand, this determines the version of `delete-selection-mode`.)

Comment: What is the value of `TeX-electric-mode`?

Comment: @rogerl: How did you evaluate that code? It should work I think. See also [tex.el:6315](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/tree/tex.el?id=release_11_89#n6315), they marked some commands, it seems `TeX-insert-dollar` was missed.

Comment: @npostavs Interesting. Perhaps I should ask the AucTeX folks about that. Thanks.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen if `TeX-electric-math` (not `TeX-electric-mode`, I guess it was a type ;-) I confirm that `(put 'TeX-insert-dollar 'delete-selection t)` works as expected.

Comment: @npostavs `TeX-insert-dollar` wasn't missed, it's so by design because for the features it provides the function needs to keep alive the current selection

Comment: Actually `TeX-insert-dollar` had in the past the `delete-selection` property, but it was removed in order to provide the feature mentioned above: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/tex.el?id=d59628f1ee02abccc179c463214baddb5a17bf71

Comment: @giordano ah, then probably it should use `(put 'TeX-insert-dollar 'delete-selection #'TeX-insert-dollar-drops-current-selection)` where `TeX-insert-dollar-drops-current-selection` would be a function returns nil in case that feature will be activated.

Comment: @giordano So if I understand your comment (and the code) correctly, if some other variable is set, then typing $ will enclose the entire region in a pair of dollar signs? So why couldn't the code be a tad smarter and do the more obvious thing if that other variable is not set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AUCTeX provides the [feature](https://gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Dollar-Signs) to wrap opening and closing inline equation markers around active region on pressing `$`, when `TeX-electric-math` is non-nil (and this isn't the default).  In order to have this, the `delete-selection` property had to [be removed](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=auctex.git;a=commitdiff;h=d59628f1ee02abccc179c463214baddb5a17bf71).  Actually, its behavior can be dynamically determined by a function, so that

```lisp
(put 'TeX-insert-dollar 'delete-selection (lambda () (null TeX-electric-math)))
```

enables or disables it depending on the value of `TeX-electric-math`.  Thanks to this discussion, the above line is now [present](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=auctex.git;a=commitdiff;h=da88a3eca3107372131aa26930e548c039fe1b51) also in development version of AUCTeX.

Comment: Would that all software were this well supported.