# smartparen-latex with delete-selection-mode

Tags: auctex, smartparens, delete-selection-mode

In my emacs setup, if I have `smartparens-mode` enabled with   `smartparens-latex` and I open a latex document, type some text then select it and type any latex special command (such as `$`, `"`, `\{`, etc...) the text gets surrounded by these symbols as expected.

However, if I have `delete-selection-mode` enabled, then the text is deleted instead. Other symbols like `{`, `(`, `[` still work as expected even when `delete-selection-mode` is enabled.

The weird thing is that this used to work flawlessly before a recent update that I cannot quite track. In fact a question was posted [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21315/delete-selection-mode-and) in 2016 and an update to AUCTeX was supposed to fix this issue.

Below is the minimum init.el code that produces this problem

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)

(defun require-package (package)
  "Install PACKAGE unless already installed."
  (unless (package-installed-p package)
    (package-install package))
  )

(package-initialize)
(package-refresh-contents)
(require-package 'auctex)
(require-package 'smartparens)
(require 'smartparens)
(require 'smartparens-latex)

(delete-selection-mode t)

(defun latex-mode-defaults ()
  (smartparens-mode)
  )

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'latex-mode-defaults)
```

Comment: Sounds like an AUCTex bug. If you don't get a definitive answer here, please consider filing a bug report.

Comment: Any updates on this? Any reasonable workarounds? I'm running into the same problem and it's driving me nuts.

Comment: EDIT: Actually, going back to this (with more LISP knowledge), it seems setting `(put 'TeX-insert-quote 'delete-selection nil)` and `(put 'TeX-insert-dollar 'delete-selection nil)` works!